# Javascript Speech Synthesis

Tags: javascript

Hello people I'm currently trying to develop a web app that utilizes Javascript speech synthesis. The problem I'm facing is that when I run the code in my webpage it reads out the text in a different language than the one I have specified but when I run the same code directly in the console it reads the correct language. Where could the problem be in this code? Note that I'm running the code in Chrome.

```
            var myText = document.getElementById ('number');
            var myText2 = document.getElementById('counter');
            var msg;
            var voices;
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
            voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            console.log(voices);
            if (voices.length !== 0) {
            msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            msg.voice = voices[1];
            msg.pitch =1;
            msg.rate= 0.9;
            msg.text = myText.value + myText2.value;
            speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
            msg.lang = 'en-GB';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 200);
    timer();
```

Comment: You set `msg.lang = 'en-GB';` after `speak()`?

Comment: Hello Johnny...I have tried to put before speak() but still hasn't worked

Comment: Where is speechSynthesis coming from? Is it a module is it a browser API? You should provide all the code required to make your example work.

Comment: Hello Daniel Tate thanks for the comment. I'm using it natively in the browser. No external code involved. The way I've posted it is the way I'm using it